# Table borders in Pisa

Tags: css, django, css-tables, pisa

I'm trying to have table borders in my PDF using pisa to generate the PDF from my html page.  According to the documentation, I should use CSS to display borders in my table.  However this is not working out.  I can see the borders on my webpage, but on the generated PDF there's absent. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?  I'm using the following styles for the table:

```
table { border: 1px solid #666666;  border-collapse:collapse; border-color:#ccc; }
td, th { border: 1px solid #666666; font-size:11px; line-height:13px; border-bottom:1px solid #666666; vertical-align:top; padding:5px; font-family:"Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I forgot to update this question after I got the answer....the CSS should be in the HTML page that'll be used by pisa.  Apparently external CSS stylesheets don't work.  Hope this will someday help someone else

Comment: external stylesheet works, as it's explained below. The problem then is to know which kinds of CSS statements are supported, you'll find them in the docs. border-collapse is not one of them.

Comment: External stylesheets do work, but it's not always easy to tell if it's finding them correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Just to correct this - external css does work in PISA but you need to ensure it can locate the css at render time. See [django - pisa : adding images to PDF output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179958/django-pisa-adding-images-to-pdf-output) for more infor on how to do this.

Regards

Tim

Answer (score 3):

For me, it worked if i **assigned a class** for it.
for example to draw a border around the cell, use below css class:

```
td.box{
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

in td, add the class:

```
<td class="box"> Something </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

the solution was:
 1 - CSS should be in the HTML page, 
 2 - CSS should be out of @page attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `display:block` for `<table>` and `<td>` elements solved this problem for me.