# Using an image URL for link_callback in the pisa html to pdf library

Tags: python, pdf-generation, pisa

Related to: [django - pisa : adding images to PDF output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179958/django-pisa-adding-images-to-pdf-output)

I've got a site that uses the Google Chart API to display a bunch of reports to the user, and I'm trying to implement a PDF version. I'm using the `link_callback` parameter in `pisa.pisaDocument` which works great for local media (css/images), but I'm wondering if it would work with remote images (using a google charts URL).

From the [documentation](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/doc/pisa-en.html) on the pisa website, they imply this is possible, but they don't show how:

> Normaly pisa expects these files to be found on the local drive. They may also be referenced relative to the original document. But the programmer might want to **load form different kind of sources like the Internet via HTTP requests** or from a database or anything else.

This is in a Django project, but that's pretty irrelevant. Here's what I'm using for rendering:

```
html = render_to_string('reporting/pdf.html', keys,
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
result = StringIO.StringIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(
        StringIO.StringIO(html.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')),
        result, link_callback=link_callback)
return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
```

I tried having the link_callback return a urllib request object, but it does not seem to work:

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    if uri.find('chxt') != -1:
        url = "%s?%s" % (settings.GOOGLE_CHART_URL, uri)
        return urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))
```

The PDF it generates comes out perfectly except that the google charts images are not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this was a whole lot easier than I expected. In your `link_callback` method, if the uri is a remote image, simply return that value.

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    if uri.find('chart.apis.google.com') != -1:
        return uri
    return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))
```

The browser is a lot less picky about the image URL, so make sure the uri is properly quoted for pisa. I had space characters in mine which is why it was failing at first (replacing w/ '+' fixed it).

Comment: PDF still not displaying Google Chart for me - [link](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chd=t:425.9,550.6&chs=400x125&chds=0,600&chl=Aug%2009|) - but I can include resources from other websites.  Any tips?

Comment: Did you try replacing the space in "Aug 9" to be "Aug+9"?

Comment: No luck, I'm afraid.  But thanks for the reply!  The really strange thing is that I can get remote resources just fine ...

Comment: Finally figured it out.  Seems like Python was having difficulty reading the PNG.  Performing a **sudo apt-get install python-imaging** seemed to fix things.