# How to include Google Chart inside Pisa Document xhtml2pdf with Django

Tags: django, pisa

I'm trying to embed the Google Chart url below into a Pisa xhtml2pdf PDF, but can't seem to make it work.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chd=t:425.9,550.6&chs=400x125&chds=0,600&chl=Aug%2009%7CSep%2009&chco=8BC542&chbh=32,24

I was hoping this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000951/using-an-image-url-for-link-callback-in-the-pisa-html-to-pdf-library) would solve my problem but no luck.

I'm using the following code (taken from the aforementioned post)

```py
html = render_to_string('reporting/pdf.html', keys,
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
result = StringIO.StringIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(
        StringIO.StringIO(html.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')),
        result, link_callback=link_callback)
return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
```

and

```py
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    if uri.find('chart.apis.google.com') != -1:
        return uri
    if uri.find('mydomain.com') != -1:
        return uri
    return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))
```

It works when I embed images from **mydomain.com** but I get nothing when trying to link to **chart.apis.google.com**

This works:

> `<img src="http://mydomain.com/foo.jpg>`

This is broken:

> `<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chd=t:425.9,550.6&chs=400x125&chds=0,600&chl=Aug%2009|">`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers.