# Pdf alignment issue when converting from html

Tags: html, django, pdf

Iam working in django. I converted the html code of

```
<table border="1">
            <tr height="50px"><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>
            <tr height="220px"><td>Description</td></tr>
            <tr height="50px"><td>Mail</td></tr>
</table>
```

into pdf using pisa in django. All are going well except the alignment. I need the row spacing in pdf as i mentioned in the html table height.
Can anyone Please help me to get the same alignment in pdf (row spacing) as same as html?

Comment: I followed the views from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410976/django-pdf-with-logo-image and i used the above html lines in "invoice.html".

Answer (score 0):

This is bad coding practice.You should do all the alignments in a separate CSS and not in html.

Comment: Eventhough i tried css for height, iam not getting the pdf alignment properly as in html