# Creating pdf from html with xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, css, django, xhtml2pdf

I want to create a pdf report from an html file and I am running in to two problems. Allgnment and fonts

For the first I have the following

```
<style>

    @font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf");
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf");
        font-style: italic, oblique;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf");
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic, oblique;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("DejaVuSansMono.ttf ");
    }
    .table {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color:#FCF0FB;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 3px;
    }
    @page {
        margin: 1cm;
        margin-bottom: 2.5cm;
        size: a4 portrait;
        margin-top:1cm;
        @frame header {
            -pdf-frame-content: headerContent;
            -pdf-frame-border:1cm;
            height:2cm;
            top: 2cm;
            margin-left:1cm;
            margin-right: 1cm;
        }

        @frame main {
            top:4cm;
            margin-left:1cm;
            margin-right:1cm;
            height:10cm;
            -pdf-frame-border: 1cm;
        }

        @frame footer {
            -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
            -pdf-frame-border: 1cm;
            bottom: 2cm;
            margin-left: 1cm;
            margin-right: 1cm;
            height:1cm;
        }
    }
    *, html{
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        font-style:normal;
        font-size 10px;

    }
    .margin-10{
        margin-bottom:10;
    }
</style>


<div class="header" id="headerContent">
    <h3>Header content</h3>

</div>
<div class="margin-10"></div>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Today's appointments</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Patient</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
                <th>Doctor</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {%for doctor, entries in today.items%}
                {%for entry in entries%}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                        <td>{{entry.start|date:"H:i"}}</td>
                        <td>{{entry.patient}}</td>
                        <td>{{entry.comment}}</td>
                        <td>{{entry.doctor}}</td>

                    </tr>
                {%endfor%}
            {%endfor%}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="footer" id="footerContent">
    <p>Για το Ιατρείο <pdf:pagenumber></p>
</div>
```

I want to have a header some margin and then the footer. But the margin-10 class I created isn't adding any margin between header and html content

In my footer I have a greek letter that is streesed greek letter. The letter won't appear normally but as a black square. I have added DejaVusans fonts in my media folders of my project, but still it won't work.

The pdf creation code

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'fonts'))
print "Path: ", path
def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(rel, uri))
    print uri
    print "Path:", path
    print 'rel: ', rel
    return path

def write_to_pdf(template, context_dict, filename=None):
    #template = Template(template_data)
    template = get_template(template)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result, path=path, encoding="UTF-8")
    if not pdf.err:
       response = http.HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        #response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf' % filename
        response.write(result.getvalue())
        return response
    return http.HttpResponse('Problem creating PDF: %s' % cgi.escape(html))
```

This is what is printed in terminal from the print statements above

```
DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

That is it sees the fonts. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your defining fetch_resources but you don't appear to be using it in pisa.PisaDocument, see - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7584674/188955

Comment: Thank you I wasn't using correct path. Though now fonts are always Italic. Is it because it have it in the font-face selectors? But in my html selector i use plain "DejavuMono" not italic.

Comment: I'm not sure on the second part, its not because of the space at the end of the last ttf maybe? Or possibly the ordering. Other then that I'm not sure

Comment: space?What do you mean be space. In the last font-face selector or in the html selector? I am not seeing it.

Comment: src: url("DejaVuSansMono.ttf "); has a space after .ttf - but no idea if that would cause an issue

Comment: Nope you were right, it didn't change anything..That was not the issue. Thanks anyway.