# python3 print webpage to pdf

Tags: python, html2pdf

I am trying to print a webpage to pdf (cutepdf), but am unable to interact with the the dialog that display programmatically using Python 3 (windows OS).

So for instance if I was using the following:

driver.execute_script("window.print()")

How would I programmatically edit the filename and then click on the save button on the 'Save As' window that appears?

Thanks in advance for assistance on this matter.

Comment: are you sure you need to use cutepdf? Have you tried this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7584674/6053327

Comment: No - I mentioned as that is installed on my machine. I actually have installed pdfkit and have managed to create the pdf file however it runs into a issue:    raise IOError('wkhtmltopdf reported an error:\n' + stderr)
OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error: So just looking into this now...Thanks though,