# while html to pdf converting with pisa hindi words are in coded way

Tags: python, django

while converting Hindi words in HTML to pdf by using the xhtml2pdf library in Django projects I am getting some coded words on how to convert in the correct way?

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
  template = get_template(template_src)
  html  = template.render(context_dict)
  result = BytesIO()
 
  pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result, encoding='UTF-8')
  if not pdf.err:
      return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
  return None
```

[image: pdf image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an encoding issue. To test this, you can render the template with Django:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
  template = get_template(template_src)
  html  = template.render(context_dict)

  return HttpResponse(html)
```

and convert manually to PDF by opening the Django URL with the `xhtml2pdf` command line utility:

`xhtml2pdf -s http://127.0.0.1:8000/quarter_notification_pdf/`

If this produces a legible PDF file, the issue is with your code. Here is the official `xhtml2pdf` documentation on how to use it with Django: https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django . They use the `CreatePDF()` function.

Another answer dealing with `xhtml2pdf`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7584674/4613449

For some alternatives: [How to convert webpage into PDF by using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23359083/4613449)