# xhtml2pdf does not show image always

Tags: image, xhtml2pdf

I use xhmtl2pd tool to convert html to pdf.  Here is a piece of my html

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:10px;vertical-align:top">&bull; </td>
    <td style="padding:0 0 5px 0;width:200px;display:inline-block">
        blah blah <br/>              
        <img src="images/little-gray-arrow.png" height="10" width="11" alt="blah" /> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

The bizarre thing is if I remove the br tag then the image of little-gray-arrow.png never shows up. Put the br tag back, the image shows up in the "next" line.
I have tried with all options, padding, margin, and none works.

I also try to inline-displaying an image between text, and the image clock.png bottom half always get cut off, regardless what I tried.

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:10px;vertical-align:top">&bull; </td>
    <td style="padding:0 0 5px 0;width:200px;">
        Wait
        <img src="images/clock.png" height="20" width="20" alt="20" />
        minutes
    </td>
</tr>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem and it is just the way xhmtl2pdf is.
Can the xhtml2pdf display image inline?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Dont use absolute paths in url or src. Use fullpath like https://abcd.com/.../image.png . It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you need render image format like GIF or PNG, you should install [PIL library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). The Python Imaging Library (PIL) is requred by ReportLab for handling PNG/GIF image.

Refer: [Output image to pdf with xhtml2pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977673/output-image-to-pdf-with-xhtml2pdf)