# Cant get images to convert to pdf using xhtml2pdf (url of file returning errror)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, xhtml2pdf

Here is a supposed solution I have found. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2180417

I am trying to implement it but I am not able to do so.

Here is my current code:

**utils.py**

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
     template = get_template(template_src)
     html  = template.render(context_dict)
     result = BytesIO()
     pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result, link_callback=fetch_resources)
     if not pdf.err:
          return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
     return None

def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))

    return path
```

**views.py**

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from django.views.generic import View

 from yourproject.utils import render_to_pdf #created in step 4

 class GeneratePdf(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         data = {
              'today': datetime.date.today(), 
              'amount': 39.99,
             'customer_name': 'Cooper Mann',
             'order_id': 1233434,
         }
         pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice.html', data)
         return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Everything loads correctly if I just render a normal template so I know the problem is with this part of the process. The invoice.html template includes a url such as /home/images/products/1231

```
<img src='{{ photo.url }}'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render the image inside the pdf you need to make an image callback with the following function:

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    """
    Convert HTML URIs to absolute system paths so xhtml2pdf can access those
    resources
    """
    # use short variable names
    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL      # Typically /static/
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT    # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL       # Typically /static/media/
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT     # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/

    # convert URIs to absolute system paths
    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
    else:
        return uri  # handle absolute uri (ie: http://some.tld/foo.png)

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
            raise Exception(
                'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl)
            )
    return path
```

Next you add your rendering function.

Link: [Biblioteca xhtml2pdf](http://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django)

If this answer has helped you, mark it as an answer.

Comment: Does it return any errors? If so, what error does it show?

Comment: warning must be a valid url

Comment: can you render the image on an html page?

Answer (score 1):

no need set the fetch resources. its works for me

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
     return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

also try to refer this link [html-template-to-pdf-in-django](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/)

Comment: Are you rendering images as well? I had this exact code and it did not work.

Comment: if so what does your view look like?

Comment: what does your view look like

Comment: Can you refer what I have gave one link

Comment: Bro thats the tutorial I used. even in his youtube comments he acknowledges that images are not rendered

Comment: it says warning needs to be a valid file... the images that are being entered are being entered as urls such as /home/products/12312.jpg

Comment: @questnofinterest, hey, have you found a fix for this, please?