# Django images NOT showing when exporting template as PDF

Tags: django, python-2.7

I've been looking for and trying out quite some solutions for this problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179958/django-pisa-adding-images-to-pdf-output), [here](https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf/issues/16) and many more) but I'm still not able to fix this.

So, I'm using `PDFViewMixin` to export a template as a PDF:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import TemplateResponseMixin

class ExportViewMixin(TemplateResponseMixin):
    filename = None
    content_type = 'text/html'

    def get_filename(self):
        return self.filename

    def get_content_type(self):
        return self.content_type

    def document_to_response(self, response, context=None):
        raise NotImplementedError('Subclasses must implement this method')

    def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type=self.get_content_type())
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="%s"' % self.get_filename()
        self.document_to_response(response, context=context)
        return response

 class PDFViewMixin(ExportViewMixin):
   '''Generic view that render a template into a PDF 
   and return it as response content.
   '''
   content_type = 'application/pdf'

   def gen_pdf(self, context):
       template = get_template(self.template_name)
       # need absolute_uris to correctly get static files
       try:
           html_doc = HTML(string=template.render(Context(context)), base_url=context.get('base_url'))
       except TypeError:       # Django>=1.11
           html_doc = HTML(string=template.render(context), base_url=context.get('base_url'))
       return html_doc.render()

   def document_to_response(self, response, context=None):
       self.gen_pdf(context).write_pdf(response)

   def get_context_data(self, **context):
       context = super(PDFViewMixin, self).get_context_data(**context)
       context['base_url'] = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
       context['content_type'] = self.get_content_type()
       return context
```

The view that controls the template inherits from `PDFViewMixin` and django `DetailView`. In the template I try to render the model's `ImageField` as follows (which perfectly works before exporting it):

```
{% if object.image %}
   <img src="{{ object.image.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

I believe (as pointed out [here](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/182#issuecomment-41899468)) the problem to be that the `render_to_response` acts like AnonymousUser and white it tries to fetch the image through login, gets an error. Indeed, this is the requests log I get in the console:

```
[27/Feb/2019 11:05:10] "GET /login/?next=/media/images/0013/765-default-avatar.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3379
WARNING: Failed to load image at "http://localhost:8000/media/images/0013/765-default-avatar.png" (Pixbuf error: Unrecognized image file format)
```

I've tried setting up a custom photo_url_fetcher (like [this](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/182#issuecomment-42015670)), using absolute uri but with no results. Does someone have a working solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After various attempts I found this solution:

- Add a method to get the image's path in the model

  ```
  def get_image_path(self):
      if image:
          return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.path)
      return ''
  ```
- Prepend `file://` to the path in the template

  `<img src="file://{{ obj.get_image_path }}">`